# Stability of periodic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am stuck on this question:

> $$x'(t) = x(x-p(t))(x-1),$$ where $p$ is $1$-periodic and $0< p(t) <1$ for all $t$. We want to show the existence of a STABLE periodic solution $\mu$ such that $0< \mu(t) <1$ for all $t$.

If we require $0< x_0 <1$, where we impose the initial condition that $x(0) = x_0$, then it is clear that there exists a solution $\mu$ that satisfies the ODE with this initial condition. Standard result also shows the existence of such periodic solutions. My question is how to show the stability of such solutions by the definition of stable periodic solutions.

Comment: Looks to me like: (i) If $x(t) \in [p(t), 1)$ then $x'(t) \leq 0$. (ii) If $x(t) \in (0, p(t)]$ then $x'(t) \geq 0$.

Comment: So in particular of there are constants $p_{min}, p_{max}$ such that $0 < p_{min} \leq p(t) \leq p_{max} < 1$ for all $t$, then $p_{min} \leq x(t) \leq p_{max}$ for all $t$, provided this holds for the initial condition $x(0)$. That seems pretty stable to me.

Comment: @Michael Usually it's meant to be (asymptotic) Lyapunov stability, but your variant is not close to any of these two variants.

Comment: @Evgeny : Well now, I solved what I could.  Would be interested in seeing a more detailed analysis that says solutions that start within $\epsilon$ of the 1-periodic solution stay within that distance, for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$.  This seems true in the special case $p(t)=constant$ for all $t$.  Also, I think if $y(t)=x^*(t)+g(t)$, where $x^*(t)$ is the 1-periodic solution, you get an ODE $g'(t) = -R(t)g(t)$, where $R(t)$ is _nonnegative_ if $g(0)$ is sufficiently small and if $1/2<x^*(t)< 2/3$ for all $t$, though there is no reason for $x(t)$ to satisfy that.

Comment: I suppose another observation is that $|x'(t)| \leq 1/4$ for all $t$, so $|x^*(t)-x^*(0)| \leq 1/8$ for all $t$ (where $x^*(t)$ is any 1-periodic solution).

Comment: @Michael I might be mistaken, but my idea is the following. I suggest to use cross-section. Since the system is $1$-periodic in $t$, it's really defined on a cylinder. Take a small $\varepsilon$ and consider a set $\lbrace 0 \rbrace \times \lbrack p_{min}-\varepsilon, p_{max}+\varepsilon \rbrack$ on $(t, x)$ plane. Consider all trajectories that start at this set and watch where do they intersect line $t = 1$. This would be our "time-$1$" map $f$. Because all these trajectories can't go out from set $\lbrack 0, 1 \rbrack \times  \lbrack p_{min} - \varepsilon, p_{max} + \varepsilon \rbrack $...

Comment: ...through $\lbrack 0, 1 \rbrack \times \{p_{min} - \varepsilon \}$ or $\{\lbrack 0, 1 \rbrack \times \{p_{max} + \varepsilon\}$, this mapping is well-defined and $f(\lbrack p_{min}-\varepsilon, p_{max}+\varepsilon \rbrack ) \subset \lbrack p_{min}-\varepsilon, p_{max}+\varepsilon \rbrack$. Mapping $f$ is continuous, it's increasing in $x$ (because integral curves don't intersect), so it's graph is just monotonous continuous function. Because $f(a) > a$ and $f(b) < b$, we clearly have point at which $f(x) = x$ hence there is a periodic solution. Because map $f$ is increasing, it means that....

Comment: ....all solutions that started at cross-section close to periodic solution will become closer after $1$ unit of time has passed. And this proves that the periodic solution is asymptotic Lyapunov stable.

Comment: @Evgeny Sorry, I don't understand your notations: What is f? (I assume that f depends on both x and t.) Also, I don't understand what you mean by a and b.

Comment: @Richard : I think Evgeny's map is $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(z)$ is the value of $x(1)$ given $x(t)$ is an ODE solution with initial condition $x(0)=z$.

Comment: @Evgeny : I follow your proof of existence of periodic solution, but I think we may need to assume $p$ is continuous. One other loose end: It is intuitive, but not clear to me how to prove, that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Evgeny : I agree that (under mild assumptions?) solutions don't cross, perhaps due to a uniqueness theorem that I am not comfortable stating rigorously, so $f$ is monotonic increasing.  But I do not see how this helps to show solutions get closer.

Comment: @Richard : By the way, Evgeny's $a,b$ are $a=p_{min}-\epsilon$ and $b=p_{max}+\epsilon$. So $0<a<p_{min}<p_{max}<b<1$. Evgeny says $f(a)>a$ because we know the derivative of $x(t)$ is positive as long as $x(t)<p_{min}$, and that $x(t)$ never goes below $p_{min}$ once it reaches it.  If we know $f$ is continuous and $f(a)>a$, $f(b)<b$, there must be an $x^* \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x^*)=x^*$.

Comment: @Michael I assumed only that $p(t)$ is continuous. With this assumption two theorems would be applicable: first one is uniqueness and existence theorem, second one is that solutions continuously depend on time and initial conditions. I use the second theorem when I state that mapping $f$ is continuous. Also, because the first theorem is applicable, we can say that map $f$ is injective (otherwise two different integral curves would intersect). Mapping $f$ is continuous, injective -- it only could be a monotonic map of segment, just no way.

Comment: @Michael I've extended my comments.

Comment: @Evgeny  : the first half of your extended comments seem to emphasize the things we already know (definition of $f$, fact that $f$ is nondecreasing, fact that there is an $x^*$ such that $f(x^*)=x^*$).  The stability issue still seems unclear.

Comment: @Michael If it is an extended answer, I have to gather solid (or almost solid) explanations for (almost) all steps :) The stability of periodic orbit follows from stability of corresponding fixed point of map at cross-section (Poincare map). This is one of the key facts and key methods for doing such things.

Comment: @Evgeny : It sounds like you are claiming all period-1 solutions to this problem are stable...are you really making that claim?

Comment: @Michael I claim that there's only one 1-periodic solution. And yes, it's stable.

Comment: @Evgeny : I do not see anywhere in your solution an argument that there should be only one.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay, so here is a proof that $f$ is continuous (which takes care of a detail in Evgeny’s proof of existence of a fixed point of $f$).

#### Setup:

Recall the ODE is:
$$ x’ = x(x-p)(x-1) $$
Assume $p$ is integrable and there are values $p_{min}, p_{max}$ such that for all $t$ we have
$$ 0<p_{min}\leq p(t) \leq p_{max} < 1 $$
Further impose any additional mild assumptions so that solutions with a given initial condition exist, are unique, and do not cross (perhaps we need $p$ continuous for that?)

Let $a,b$ be values such that $0<a<p_{min}<p_{max}<b<1$.
Define Evgeny’s function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that for each $z \in [a,b]$, the value $f(z)$ is defined as  $x(1)$ for a solution $x(t)$ to the ODE with initial condition $x(0)=z$.  We want to show $f$ is continuous over $[a,b]$.

#### Proof:

Fix $z \in [a,b]$.  Fix a small value $\delta \neq 0$ such that $z+\delta \in [a,b]$.  We want to show that $|f(z+\delta)-f(z)| \leq |\delta|D$ for some positive constant $D$.   Define $x(t)$ as the ODE solution with $x(0)=z$.  Define $y(t)$ as the ODE solution with $y(0)=z+\delta$.  Define $g(t) = y(t) - x(t)$, so that $g(0) = \delta$.  Since $y=x+g$ we get:
$$ y’ = x’ + g’  = x(x-p)(x-1) + g’ $$
On the other hand, since $y$ satisfies the ODE we get:
$$ y’ = y(y-p)(y-1) = (x+g)(x+g-p)(x+g-1) $$
Equating the above two expressions gives:
$$ x(x-p)(x-1) + g’ = (x+g)(x+g-p)(x+g-1) $$
and so:
$$ g’ = y’ - x’ = g\underbrace{[g^2 - gp + 3gx - g - 2px + p + 3x^2 -2x]}_{R(t)} $$
That is, for all $t$ we have
$ g’(t) = g(t)R(t) $.
Now, we already know (from above comments) that any solution to the ODE with initial condition in $[a,b]$ must *stay* in $[a,b]$.  Thus, $x,y, g$ are bounded  for all time, and there is some positive constant $C$ such that $|R(t)| \leq C$ for all $t$.
For all $t$ we have  $g(t) \neq 0$  (since $\delta\neq 0$ and solutions cannot cross). Thus:
$$ \frac{g’(t)}{g(t)} = R(t)$$
So for all $t \geq 0$:
$$ \log[|g(t)|/|g(0)|] = \int_0^t R(\tau)d\tau $$
So
$$ |g(t)| = |g(0)|e^{\int_0^t R(\tau)d\tau} = |\delta|  e^{\int_0^tR(\tau)d\tau} \leq |\delta| e^{Ct} $$
Thus:
$$ |f(z+\delta) - f(z)| = |y(1) - x(1)| = |g(1)| \leq |\delta| e^{C} $$
$\Box$

Comment: Aha, an unexplained downvote several weeks after the answer.  Not a very helpful or mathematical thing to do.

Comment: This downvote is mine. Although everything is correct here and I like the idea that you've used, in my opinion your answer doesn't serve the purpose. The fact that ODE solutions continuously depend on time and initial conditions is fundamental and it is presented in all more or less serious ODE courses. The continuity of mapping $f$ simply follows from this theorem. Again, in my opinion, I don't see why your proof of this fact can be counted as an answer to original question of stability. Hence the downvote.

Comment: @Evgeny : You have an interesting way to show your appreciation for my help.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let me explain my idea in full extent. First of all, instead of considering first order ODE, I consider an equivalent system of ODEs:

$$ \dot{x} = x(x - p(\tau))(x - 1), \;\; \dot{\tau} = 1 . $$

It's easy to verify that integral curves of original ODE are the same as integral curves of this system.
Also, from this form we get that vector field that is defined by this system is 1-periodic in $\tau$: if $(\tilde{x}(t), t)$ is a solution then $(\tilde{x}(t), t + k)$ is also a solution for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. This symmetry naturally allows us to consider behaviour of trajectories only in strip $(t, x) \in \lbrack 0, 1 \rbrack \times (-\infty, +\infty)$ because behaviour of any full trajectory can be "glued" using the "data" from the strip.

**From here I'll assume that $p(\tau)$ is a continuous function.
This allows us to use two theorems immediately:**
**1. Existence and uniqueness theorem. The uniqueness part simply means that integral curves either coincide or have empty intersection.**
**2. Denote by $w(t; w_0) = (\tau(t), x(t))$ the solution that satisfies IVP $w(0; w_0) = w_0 = (\tau_0, x_0)$. Then function $F(t, u) = w(t; u)$ is continuous w.r.t. $t$ and $u$.**

The purpose of the following part is two-fold: it proves that there is a 1-periodic solution and it shows that it is asymptotically Lyapunov stable. I don't know what kind of theorem you used for showing that there is a periodic motion, but I believe that my explanation will be quite simple. Here's an illustration:

[image: Cross-section]

As I've said earlier, choose $a$ and $b$ in such way that $0 < a < p_{min} < p_{max} < b < 1$ holds. You can simply check that vector field points along boundary in the same way as on the figure. Such configuration allows us to tell that all trajectories that start at $(\tau, x) \in \lbrace 0 \rbrace \times \lbrack a, b \rbrack$ can leave $(\tau, x) \in \lbrack 0, 1 \rbrack \times \lbrack a, b \rbrack$ only through $(\tau, x) \in \lbrace 1 \rbrace \times \lbrack a, b \rbrack$. To be absolutely precious, you might check vector field at points $(1, a)$ and $(1, b)$, see that trajectories that start at them leave 
$(\tau, x) \in \lbrack 0, 1 \rbrack \times \lbrack a, b \rbrack$ in backward time and conclude that all trajectories escape strip only through 
$(\tau, x) \in \lbrace 1 \rbrace \times ( a, b )$.

It's time to define "time-1 mapping". We define it by formula

$$ f(x) = F(1, (0, x)).$$

This is a continuous mapping of segment $\lbrack a, b \rbrack$ into itself. 
If we were interested only in proving existence of periodic solution (i.e.,
which has $f(x) = x$), we could use a [Brouwer fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem) (which
states that such fixed point exists).
But we need to investigate the stability and we can use simpler arguments. Note that $f(a) > a$ and $f(b) < b$, so $f(a) - a > 0$ and $f(b) - b < 0$; because $f$ is continuous there exists a point $\hat{x}$ where $f(\hat{x}) - \hat{x} = 0$. Therefore, we proved that $f(x)$ has fixed point and our system of ODEs has a 1-periodic solution.

But we can prove more! Recall that I've said that in this case $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing function. It's very simple to prove. Pick any point $(0, x^\ast)$ and consider the integral curve that is passing through this point. As we already know, it will intersect line $\tau = 1$ at point $(1, f(x^\ast)$. Now consider the closed domain $G$ which is bounded by lines $\gamma$,
$\lbrace 0 \rbrace \times \lbrack a, x^\ast \rbrack$, $\lbrack 0, 1 \rbrack \times \lbrace a \rbrace$ and $\lbrace 1 \rbrace \times \lbrack a, f(x^\ast) \rbrack$. By construction there is only one way to escape $G$ -- only through the $\lbrace 1 \rbrace \times \lbrack a, f(x^\ast) \rbrack$ (because escaping through $\gamma$ will violate uniqueness theorem). But this simply means that for any $x \in (a, x^\ast)$ follows $f(x) < f(x^\ast)$. And it holds for any $x^\ast \in (a, b \rbrack$, which simply means that $f(x)$ is increasing function.

But what does that all mean for stability of periodic motion?
 <s>Here is another illustration:</s>

[image: Cobweb diagram]

<s>It's a [cobweb diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot) for our mapping $f$. It's easy to prove that iterations of any point from segment $\lbrack a, b \rbrack$ converge to fixed point. It means that after each period any other solution "starts" at cross-section closer and closer to periodic solution. Using some $\epsilon$-$\delta$ machinery you can prove that periodic solution is [asymptotic Lyapunov stable](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Stability#Asymptotic_stability), but we already have the key fact that fixed point on cross-section is attractive. After that the proof should be quite simple.</s>

**EDIT**

As @Michael pointed out, my illustration is not the only possibility for cobweb diagram. There could be other fixed points as well: at some of them $y = f(x)$ might touch $y=x$ and at some of them they might be intersecting transversely.
The key observation is that there should exist a fixed point $\hat{x}$ such that $f(x) > x$ for $x \in \lbrack \hat{x}-\varepsilon, \hat{x} )$ and
$f(x) < x$ for $x \in ( \hat{x}, \hat{x} +\varepsilon \rbrack$. Why such fixed point exists? It's due to these facts:
1) $y = f(x)$ starts in the $y > x$ part of square $\lbrack a, b \rbrack \times \lbrack a, b \rbrack$ and ends in the 
$y < x$ part;
2) we definitely have fixed points for $y = f(x)$.

By reductio ad absurdum we could show that if we have no such fixed points, then curve $y = f(x)$ stays only in $y \geqslant x$ part of square which contradicts the first fact.

The fixed point with such properties would be attractive and will correspond to the stable periodic solution.

Comment: Your comments and above answer suggest this is true at every point $x^*$ such that $x^*=f(x^*)$, but your cobweb picture need not apply to all such cases.  For example, the red curve might be _under_ the black on the left-hand-side, in which case the point $x^*$ is _unstable_.  If there are many crossings and many points $x_i$ such that $f(x_i)=x_i$ you might argue that there is one with the above picture, but there are also stranger possibilities of infinite crossings with "infinitessimal" distances between crossings.

Comment: @Michael why are you pointing to the general case when this cobweb diagram is made **specially** for this time-1 mapping? It represents $f(x)$ that I've defined and nothing more.

Comment: Evgeny:  I do not see the purpose of your comment above. Overall, it seems you are unintentionally (or intentionally?)  claiming that for all points $x^*$ that satisfy $f(x^*)=x^*$ in your $f$ function, we must also have  $f(x^*-\epsilon)\geq f(x^*) - \epsilon$ and $f(x^*+\epsilon) \leq f(x^*)+\epsilon$ for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to show that I claim. I've listed all properties of function $f(x)$ that I use and gave an explanation why they appear here. What am I unintentionally claiming?

Comment: Why does the (second) red curve look that way?  Might it not have many such points $f(x_i)=x_i$?  Might it not "kiss" the 45 degree line several times before crossing?  All of these are possible and consistent with $f$ increasing.

Comment: @Michael Oh my God. And you couldn't say earlier that assuming $f(x)$ is strictly increasing is not enough to plot the diagram this way. Okay, let me think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31323/discussion-between-michael-and-evgeny).