# Prove that there is a periodic solution $x(t)$ with $p<x(0)<q$

Tags: dynamical-systems

> Consider the differential equation $x'=f(t,x)$, where $f(t,x)$ is continuously differentiable in $t$ and $x$.
>
> Suppose that $f(t+T,x)=f(t,x)$ for all $t$ . Suppose there are constants $p$, $q$ such that $f(t,p)>0,f(t,q)<0$ for all $t$. Prove that there is a periodic solution $x(t)$ for this equation with $p<x(0)<q$

What I have to show is that $ x(t+T) = x(t) $, that is $x(t)$ is periodic. I tried this

$\int_{0}^{t}{x'} = x(t)-x(0) = \int_{0}^{t}{f(s,x(s))}ds  $

But I don't know how to continue...

Comment: It would be good if you told us what your knowledge of time-periodic DEs is. Do you know, for instance, that periodic solutions are in one-to-one correspondence with fixed points of the period map? Then the problem reduces to the Darboux property of the period map.

Comment: if $p(x_{0}) = x_{0}$, that is $x_{0}$ is a fixed point of the Poincaré map, then 
the solution  satisfying  $x(0) = x_{0}$ is periodic.

Comment: The symbol $p$ already means some point, so it's better to denote the Poincaré map by $P$. From the assumptions it follows that $P(p)>p$ and $P(q)<q$, By uniqueness, $P(p)\le P(q)$. So, $p<P(p)\le P(q)<q$, and by the Darboux property of the continuous function $P$ on $[p,q]$, there is $x_0\in(p,q)$ such that $P(x_0)=x_0$. (What I wrote here is only a sketch: to have a complete proof one has to show that, under the assumptions, $P$ is defined for all $x\in[p,q]$.)

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515353/stability-of-periodic-solution/1519112#1519112) will provide a useful illustration. Also, in principle there could be multiple fixed points of Poincaré map, but one of them is necessarily stable.

Comment: @Evgeny Now I can imagine what is happening. We know that there are constants $p, q$ such that $f(t,p)>0$ ,$f(t,q)<0$ but how do we know that $ p < q $?...

Comment: @tnt235711 In case $ p > q$ you can consider the problem in backward time: all arrows would be reversed, and the picture would be the same as in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Poincaré map is defined in the following way:

> For $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$, $P(\xi)$ is defined as the value at time $T$ of the (unique) solution of the IVP $$\begin{cases} x'= f(t,x), \\ x(0) = \xi. \end{cases}$$

It is easy to see that fixed points of the Poincaré map are in a one-to-one correspondence with the values at time $t = 0$ of $T$-periodic solutions of the ODE $x' = f(t, x)$ (here $T$ need not be the prime period).

Let $\varphi$ (resp. $\psi$) stand for the nonextendible solution of the ODE satisfying $\varphi(0) = p$ (resp. $\psi(0) = q$).  It follows from the uniqueness property that 
$$
\varphi(t) < \psi(t)
$$
for all $t \ge 0$ for which both $\varphi(t)$ and $\psi(t)$ exist.

Denote by $(\alpha, \beta)$ the domain of $\varphi$.  We claim that $\varphi(t) > p$ for all $t \in (0, \beta)$.  Observe that $\varphi(t) > p$ for $t > 0$ sufficiently small.  Suppose to the contrary that $\tau$ is the first moment in $(0, \beta)$ such that $\varphi(\tau) = p$.  But $\varphi'(\tau) = f(\tau, p) > 0$, a contradiction.  In a similar way we prove that $\psi(t) < q$ for all $t > 0$ for which $\psi(t)$ exists.

Note that, by uniqueness, for any $x \in [p, q]$ the solution of the ODE starting at $x$ takes, for positive times, the values in the compact set $[p, q]$ (as long as it is defined).  Consequently, the domain of such a solution contains $[0, \infty)$.

To sum up, we have proved that the continuous (indeed, $C^1$) Poincaré map maps $[p, q]$ into $[P(p), P(q)] \subset (p, q)$.  By the Darboux property of continuous functions applied to 
$$
[p, q] \ni x \mapsto P(x) - x
$$
there exists $x_0 \in (p, q)$ such that $P(x_0) = x_0$.  So, the solution of the ODE starting at $x_0$ has period $T$.

Comment: How do we know that the Poincare map is continuous? Is it just because $f(t,x)$ is continuously differentiable? Or are there other requirements? Can you point me to a proof of that? Thanks!

Comment: @SweepingBishops Theorems on continuous dependence of solutions of an ODE on initial values are formulated in any good textbook on ODEs.  Let’s try Gerald Teschl’s _Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems_ (accessible for personal use at https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/index.html).  From our assumptions (indeed, they can be relaxed slightly) it follows that RHS is Lipschitz continuous in $x$, uniformly with respect to $t$.  Then apply Theorem 2.8 on p. 43 to obtain continuity of the Poincaré map (or Theorem 2.9 to obtain Lipschitz continuity).