# Analysis of Time-Varying Differential Equation

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics, bifurcation

I'm trying to analyze the a differential equation of the form:

$$
\dot{x} = -K_1\sin(\omega t + x) - K_2\sin(x)
$$

where $K_1 > 0$, $K_2 > 0$, and $\omega >0$ are positive real constants and $x=x(t) \in \mathbb{R}$. If this equation did not depend on $t$, I can see immediately how I would identify the fixed points of this system and proceed with the usual stability analysis techniques. However, the dependence of $\dot{x}$ on $t$ throws me off. Is there a general method of dealing with time-varying systems like this? I would appreciate any references.

In my search, one method I found involved treating $t$ as an independent state variable, generating another equation. However, I don't see how this helps analysis.

Ultimately what I'm trying to accomplish is to determine how varying the constants can result in bifurcations (specifically, I can observe a stable equilibrium point for certain $K_1$ and $K_2$ and a limit cycle for other choices). I can confirm their presence through simulations, but I would like to obtain something more analytical.

Comment: Note that by rescaling of time and parameters you can non-dimensionalize your equation such that it will have only two essential parameters: for example, by picking $t = \alpha \tau$ and choosing $\alpha = 1/\omega$ we can transform equation into $\frac{d x}{d \tau} = -\hat{K}_1 \sin{(\tau + x)} - \hat{K}_2 \sin{x}$. I guess you might try to find Fourier series for solving this for small $\hat{K}_1$ and deducing some of stability properties from it. You can also probably get some geometric estimates for attracting region, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1519112/87697).